# How to do Website Authentication in Java Applet?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, applet, http-authentication

I have a wireless IP camera and I want to make my own web page to show its live stream.
The address of the stream is `"http://192.168.1.2:8082/index.cgi"` (supposed) and it requires User authentication. This means that when we enter the above URL in browser it asks for username and password.

All what I want is that to make a java applet, on loading the java applet, it should authenticate the URL and show the image/stream.

This is the situation, now the basic problem is that

Q: How to do Http authentication in Java applet?

I shall be thankful for every answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve it by making an [HttpURLConnection](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html) and appending username and password with the URL. As:

```
URL myURL = new URL("http://192.168.1.2:8082/index.cgi?username=user&password=");
HttpURLConnection myConnection = (HttpURLConnection) myURL.openConnection();
myConnection.setDoOutput(false);
int status = ((HttpURLConnection) myConnection).getResponseCode();
```

Alternatively (instead of appending username/password to url), you can try( not sure if it is allowed in Applet) setting the default authenticator for http requests like this:

```
Authenticator.setDefault (new Authenticator() {
    protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
        return new PasswordAuthentication ("username", "password".toCharArray());
    }
});
```

You can also use [Apache HttpComponents HttpClient](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/) which is very easy to use. To know more about how HTTP requests work in Java, see this [**answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2793153/945945).

Comment: :: my applet get starts but the authentication gives this error i am quoting the full error below 

"Exception : java.lang.RuntimeException: java.security.AccessControlException: access denied (java.net.SocketPermission 192.168.1.20:8082 connect,resolve)"

Comment: @azeemAkram Which solution are you using?  are you appending username/password in url ? or using authenticator?

Comment: the first one, appending udername/passowrd in url.

Comment: @azeemAkram: hmm .. looks like it has something to do with security. Please have a look at my answer here : http://stackoverflow.com/a/10992811/945945.