# java.lang.RuntimePermission when running a applet from the web application

Tags: java, web-applications, applet, environment-variables, tomcat6

I'm trying to read a envrionment varaible from a applet, here is my code

```
    String env = System.getenv("TWS");
    System.out.println(env);
    Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
    String s = env + "\\WebStart.bat " ;
    System.out.println(s);
    try {
        Process p = rt.exec(s);
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
```

when i run the code from netbeans by right click and run, it is running without a problem.

but when i put it to a jar file, add it to my web application and try to run it from a html page using the following code

```
<applet code="draw.class" archive='AppletTest.jar'>
   <param name="shape" value="triangle"/>
</applet>
```

i'm getting a error saying **access denied , java.lang.RuntimePermission**

i am running this web application using tomcat 6.

i have read some guides and added the following entry to catalina.policy file in tomcat 6 and restarted tomcat

```
permission java.lang.RuntimePermission "accessDeclaredMembers";
```

but still the same warning. can some one please suggest a solution for this problem?

--rangana

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you run your applet from netbeans, Java virtual machines runs it under a different security regime than when you run it through browser.

Applets, downloaded through browsers, that are not signed using a security certificate, are considered to be untrusted and referred to as unsigned applets. When running on a client, unsigned applets operate within a security sandbox that allows only a set of safe operations. You can check if a perticular permission is granted to you applet or not by using [SecurityManager](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/SecurityManager.html). For example in your case :

```
System.getSecurityManager().checkPermission(new RuntimePermission("accessDeclaredMembers"));
```

You can know more about applet security **[here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/applet/security.html)** and **[here](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/Security/applets/)**. A very nice tutorial on making signed applets can be found **[here](http://www-personal.umich.edu/~lsiden/tutorials/signed-applet/signed-applet.html)**.

Comment: +1  As an aside.  Did you post to usenet (comp.lang.java) under that same ID?

Comment: @AndrewThompson: No. Never used that.

Comment: using a signed applet i was able to achieve this task, thank you for the help :)